# Emulator for MC9190 Hand Held

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, emulation, device, handheld

I'm developing an application for a Hand Held device MC9190G, which comes with Windows Mobile 6.5, below an screenshot of the characteristic of this Hand Held

[image: Screenshot of a Hand Held MC9190]

Which would it be the best emulator for this device? I downloaded the SDK from this site : [Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17284)

Comment: Great question! Microsoft puts so much stuff out there to download it is hard to tell what needs to be installed. Sometimes their SDKs conflict with other ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To emulate a Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic device the best emulator to use is

Windows Mobile 6.5 Standard Developer Tool Kit (USA) from the above link.

You may also install and use the Professionel variant, but you nee to keep in mind that the Classic does not support the Phone (if any is built into the device you have).

According to this [site](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers/MC9190-G), this device (MC9190G) does not have a WWAN module and so the Classic version is OK.

BUT, be aware that a Emulator does NOT provide the Motorola device specific APIs like for the Barcode Scanner or there WLAN client.

I just installed "Windows Mobile 6.5 Standard Developer Tool Kit (USA).msi" from the MS site.

Here is the list of Device Emulator Images before (left) and after(right) the installation:

[image]

You can see that "USA Windows Mobile 6.5 Standard Landscape QVGA Emulator" and "USA Windows Mobile 6.5 Standard Square Emulator" are added.

Although previously stated, the WM65 Standard QVGA Landscape Emulator supports Phone too.
As it also uses an incompatible screen layout, I recommend you use Windows Mobile 6.1 or WM 6.5 Prof. emulator and avoid using Phone API.

Here is a screen shot showing the Emu Images side by side:

[image]

Did you already have a Windows Mobile 6 SDK as listed in the requirements?

Sorry, for the confusion about what MS provides and what 'names' they are using for there Windows Mobile OS series.

Comment: Thanks for answering @josef, I've downloaded the Windows Mobile 6.5 Standard Developer Tool Kit (USA) and the profosesional, but I can't find the classic version emulator, just the Professionals one

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm developing for a similar device - the MC9190-Z with RFID Reader. I'm using the **Windows Mobile Professional 6.5.3 DTK**, see here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389

"It's should be the same as WM 6.5 Professional (or Classic which is the same as Pro but with no phone support)." (source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df3c57a7-eb84-4b45-9c79-6064dd9151e4/confused-windows-embedded-handheld-65-classic-dev-setup?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs)